# Initialize NodeList Java

Tags: java, xml

I was trying to get rid of the null initialization of the NodeList, but it doesn't appear I can do:

```
NodeList compiledNodeLIst = new Nodelist();
```

When I try move it inside the try statement like so:

```
private NodeList compileToNodeList(String pattern, Document document){
            try{
                NodeList compiledNodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile("/*/UserList/User").evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

My Return variable can't be resolved and if I move that into the try block my method errors with no return statement. Below is the full statement.

```
   private NodeList compileToNodeList(String pattern, Document document){
            NodeList compiledNodeList = null;
            try{
                compiledNodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile("/*/UserList/User").evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            } catch (XPathExpressionException e){
                //TODO code for logging
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return compiledNodeList;
```

This technically is working, but I was hoping to either get rid of the null or have an explanation of why this won't be possible.

Comment: You can get rid of it by returning from both the try and the catch, but you really shouldn't stress over this sort of a thing.

Comment: You need to ask yourself if just catching the exception and continuing is the right thing to do.  Don't be afraid to throw a `RuntimeException` if it's unrecoverable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method

```
   private NodeList compileToNodeList(String pattern, Document document){
        NodeList compiledNodeList = null;
        try{
            compiledNodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile("/*/UserList/User").evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        } catch (XPathExpressionException e){
            //TODO code for logging
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return compiledNodeList;
   }
```

Is *almost* the right.  The `TODO` statement tells me you plan on just logging the error.  Are you sure that's what's expected?  You get an error from the underlying library and you don't want to tell the caller about it?  If that's true, I can just delete this "answer."  But if not, here's a better option

```
 private NodeList compileToNodeList(String pattern, Document document){
        NodeList compiledNodeList = null;
        try{
            compiledNodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile("/*/UserList/User").evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        } catch (XPathExpressionException e){
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to create the compiled node list: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return compiledNodeList;
 }
```

Throwing an exception when you get an unexpected state is ***right*** thing to do.  I'm showing a `RuntimeException` type because that's just how I roll, but you could also opt for some checked `Exception`, although that means having to deal with throwing it up the chain.

Catching the exception and creating a new `EmptyNodeList` is also feasible, assuming that's OK (not letting the caller know there was problem).

Comment: Thanks!. This actually makes a lot of sense to let the call know (which seems more obvious once you point this out.)

Answer (score 0):

Best to have the caller of this method check if the nodelist is null.

If you still must have a non-null return value (in case of exception), you can create a dummy or an anonymous implementation of NodeList and return that:

```
public static final class EmptyNodeList implements NodeList{
//no op methods
}
private NodeList compileToNodeList(String pattern, Document document){
        NodeList compiledNodeList = null;
        try{
            compiledNodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile("/*/UserList/User").evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        } catch (XPathExpressionException e){
            //TODO code for logging
            e.printStackTrace();
            compiledNodeList = new EmptyNodeList();
        }
        return compiledNodeList;
}
```

or

```
public static final NodeList emptyNodeList = new NodeList() {
    @Override
    public Node item(int index) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getLength() {
        return 0;
    }
};
```